# Clarification needed on DNS suffix not matching the FQDNS of the domain

Tags: dns, active-directory

I've got a problem with local actual Machine DNS suffix configuration info mismatching with the AD managed computer info record called "DNS Name". I'd like to know which takes precedence and whether the chosen DNS suffix should follow what DNS you choose for the domain, or whether it should follow what you choose for the network (DNS). Our AD suffixes and chosen DHCP-assigned DNS suffixes are different.

**Which takes the lead?**

> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Domain
>   HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\NV Domain

How this came about:

We have separate DNS managing DHCP objects, which get a default prefix. The MS DNS is a subzone of the Larger primary DNS. Some of our desktops started propagating errant DNS info up to AD that didn't match the actual FQDN, causing some tools to fail when trying to resolve the newly generate AD DNS entries.

For the example below: all DHCP objects receive the dhcp.domain.com suffix

> resolvable FQDN: computer.dhcp.domain.com 
>   became: computer.ou.ad.domain.com

The latter was mismatched to the FQDN, but matches the AD DNS scheme and thus does not resolve.

We manually set the two registry entries above to example.domain.com and rebooted. The AD objects update immediately to the correct suffix we applied.

Since Domain and NV Domain must match according to MS technical specifications, does it follow that the AD domain suffix and DNS suffixes must match if you do this right?

We are looking at a rollout that will span many devices so we're looking to avoid issues later on if the AD and DNS need to be better aligned now.

**So to recap - which of these is best?**

Is this correct? (what we will use now)

> [AD] AD Domain = ou.ad.domain.com
>   [Registry] Domain = dhcp.domain.com 
>   [Registry] NV Domain = dhcp.domain.com
>   [DNS] FQDN Suffix = dhcp.domain.com

or is this ultimately more correct (using MS guidance on the matter)

> [AD] Domain = ou.ad.domain.com
>   [Registry] Domain = ou.ad.domain.com
>   [Registry] NV Domain = ou.ad.domain.com
>   [DNS] FQDN Suffix = ou.ad.domain.com

Thanks for your help and guidance...especially if I can make the a cleaner presentation.